# Pygame 3D: How to and is it possible?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, 3d, pygame

So I want to program a 3d-mesh viewer in pygame, no other 3rd-party modules wanted (panda3d is perfect, but it's very complicated). My idea is:

```
list_of_surfs = {'85 50':'70deg'} #the 85 50 and the dimensions of the 
#side/surf, and 70 deg of rotation to be able to see it, then i would like
#stretch it and scale it for it to seem 3-dimensional.
```

Any ideas? This also doesn't seem to work; it's too complicated and too time consuming. So how can I make a pure-Pygame 3d-mesh viewer? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought: if you can write a better headline that states your question you might attract more and better answers to your question.

Comment: Try PyOpenGL. It's compatible with pygame, and can render 3D stuff without the pain of 3D-2D conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pygame doesn't have the ability to do this natively. If you really want this, you'll need to brush up on your trigonometry to map lines from the 3D space to the 2D screen. At that point, you'll essentially be re-implementing a 3D engine.

Comment: By the way, as long as you're willing to stick with a wireframe display, this isn't as hard as it might sound. You just need the math to translate a single 3D point onto the screen, then to display a triangle you just need to draw lines between those translated points. You don't need to worry about textures or depth buffers, or any of the other stuff a 3D engine usually cares about.